# How to get inner text value of an HTML tag with BeautifulSoup bs4?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

When using BeautifulSoup bs4, how to get text from inside a HTML tag? When I run this line:

```
oname = soup.find("title")
```

I get the `title` tag like this:

```html
<title>page name</title>
```

and now I want to get only the inner text of it, `page name`, without tags. How to do that?

Comment: @TLama  ty TLama for the correction :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use .text to get the text from the tag.

```
oname = soup.find("title")
oname.text
```

Or just `soup.title.text`

```
In [4]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup    
In [5]: import  requests
In [6]: r = requests.get("http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934387/how-to-retrieve-information-inside-a-tag-with-python/27934403#27934387")    
In [7]: BeautifulSoup(r.content).title.text
Out[7]: u'html - How to Retrieve information inside a tag with python - Stack Overflow'
```

To open a file and use the text as the name simple use it as you would any other string:

```
with open(oname.text, 'w') as f
```

Comment: i have a question how to use tis variable on the line with open('oname.text', 'w') as f:

Comment: @kibayam just pass the variable to open

Comment: Lol, @Padraic, you've got a question below ;)

Comment: It's strange that the `text` property is not mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). The nearest thing I found is the [get_text()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text) method.