# How can I get text from the links on the webpage?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib

I have specfied the url and query to search but i am just able to get the links and not the data inside it.And i need to extract text from the same url.

```
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
def lambda_handler(event=None,Context=None):
    query = "food"
    url = "https://fr.search.yahoo.com/search?p="
    Url = str(url+query)
    print Url 
    html_page = urllib.urlopen(Url).read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page,features="html.parser")
    print (soup.h)
    # print (soup.p)
    for link in soup.find_all('a'):
        print(link.get('href'))
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get inner text value of an HTML tag with BeautifulSoup bs4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934387/how-to-get-inner-text-value-of-an-html-tag-with-beautifulsoup-bs4)

Answer (score 0):

You need to explain your problem better, but if i understood your question correctly and you want to extract the text from an element you can do the following:
`soup.get_text()` or just `soup.text` i believe. And you can add this to the for loop as well, for an example `link.text`.

Comment: my use case is ,for example if i type in google.com console "aws iam" then it should be give links that are in french language and the content inside them should be french respectively.As i m not able to get links in french from google. so i have used the url in my code it hit the fr.yahoo.com and there its should query "aws iam" and give me link and then i need to extract text from those links.

Comment: and in my code i m able to get link of fr.yahoo.com where i query "food" now i need to  extract text from each link which i have got . which i m not able to get

Answer (score 0):

Use [this](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#string) in your loop

```
print(link.string)
```