# Access content of span tag in HTML

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have the following code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

url = 'https://www.drikpanchang.com/?geoname-id=5907364'

#Open web page
uClient = uReq(url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

#Parse html
page_soup = soup(page_html, 'html.parser')

keys = page_soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'dpDainikPanchangKey'})
values = page_soup.findAll('span', {'class': 'dpDainikPanchangValue'})


print(keys[5])
print(values[5])
```

The output of the code is:

```
<span class="dpDainikPanchangKey">Karana</span>
<span class="dpDainikPanchangValue">Bava <span class="dpOffColor">upto</span> 08:01 <span class="dpTimeStamp">AM</span></span>
```

How do I access 'Karana' in keys[5] and 'Bava' in values[5] and assign them to variables?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get inner text value of an HTML tag with BeautifulSoup bs4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934387/how-to-get-inner-text-value-of-an-html-tag-with-beautifulsoup-bs4)

Comment: Are those the only 2 values you want?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `var_1 = keys[5].get_text()` or `var_1 = keys[5].text`. More about the get_text() method can be found on the [bs4 documentation page](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

For `values`, use something like `var_2 = values[5].text.split()[0]` to get 'Bava'.

To explain, `.text` or `.get_text()` retrieves the text attribute of the tags you parsed.

There may be a more elegant and bespoke solution for 'Bava', but this will get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

To get the value from `keys[5]`, just do

```
keys_5 = keys[5].text.strip()
```

To get the desired value from `values[5]`,

- Use `stripped_strings` and get the first item.

  ```
  val_5 = next(values[5].stripped_strings)
  ```
- *You can also use `.contents` this way*

  ```
  val_5 = values[5].contents[0]
  ```

```
keys_5 = keys[5].text.strip()
val_5 = next(values[5].stripped_strings)

print(f'keys_5: {keys_5}')
print(f'val_5: {val_5}')
```

```
keys_5: Karana
val_5: Kaulava
```