# How to get innertext from html in python

Tags: python

I have this text:

```
<span id="valor">texto</span><span id="valor1" class="texto">Fecha
```

And I want to get:

```
textoFecha
```

Please consider that it won't always be span and they won't be always the same strings, the idea is taking all the etiquettes (between < and >) and deleting them.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get inner text value of an HTML tag with BeautifulSoup bs4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27934387/how-to-get-inner-text-value-of-an-html-tag-with-beautifulsoup-bs4)

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
text = "<span id='valor'>texto</span><span id='valor1' class='texto'>Fecha"
text = re.sub("<.*?>", "", text)
print(text)
```

This regex replace will delete anything inside the tags.
Output: textoFecha

Comment: Thanks a lot! it works like a charm. I gave you a positive vote but I'm new so it won't show it. Anyway, again, thanks man